# JavaScript Multi Dimentional Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have created a multidimensional array for a jobs feed like so:

```
var jobs = [                
        ["JOB222" , "Painter"],                 
        ["JOB333" , "Teacher"],                 
        ["JOB444" , "Delivery Driver"],             
];
```

I can access the array using the index number

```
alert( jobs[2][1] ); // Alerts Delivery Driver
```

If I set the reference number manually, I can loop through the array to find a match.

```
var viewingJobRef = "JOB333";
for (var i=0;i<jobs.length;i++) {

    if (jobs[i][0] == viewingJobRef) {
      alert(jobs[i][1]); // This will alert Teacher
    }

}
```

So my question is, is it possible to access the array directly and not use a loop?

```
var viewingJobRef = "JOB333";
alert( jobs[viewingJobRef][1] );  // I want this to alert Teacher
```

Firefox error console says:
**jobs[viewingJobRef]is undefined**, how do I do it?

Comment: Use an object instead of an array

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to use objects:

```
var jobs = {                
        "JOB222" : "Painter",                 
        "JOB333" : "Teacher",                 
        "JOB444" : "Delivery Driver"             
};
```

Access like this :

```
var viewingJobRef = "JOB333";
alert( jobs[viewingJobRef] );
```

OR

```
alert( jobs["JOB333"] );
```

OR

```
alert( jobs.JOB333 );
```

Comment: Thanks you, this works perfect, I'll use objects instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You may use objects:

```
var jobs = {
    "JOB222": "Painter",
    "JOB333": "Teacher",
    "JOB444": "Delivery Driver"
};
```

And loop with:

```
for ( var i in jobs ) {...}
```

Or access directly like:

```
alert( jobs.JOB333 );
```